# Process multiple Tasks return values in Task Parallel Library

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, return-value

I am having a problem in processing multiple tasks return values written in Task Parallel Library.

My code does as below:
. Creates set of Keys and objects with data coming from third party
. It starts task for each key in that dictionary
. In each of the task, again set of tasks will be started with user objects associated with that key (from step 2 above)
. Once all the inner tasks are executed, I want to update the user object based on the return value.

So far I have come up with the below code:

```
        void ProcessKeys(ExchangeKey eKey)
        {   
            // Create List of Tasks
            var retValues = new List<Task<ReturnStatus>>();
            // The ContainsKey here is commented out but I have a comparer method which can compare the compound keys
            if (TaskProcessor.lstInputsFromUser.Count > 0 )//  && TaskProcessor.lstInputsFromUser.ContainsKey(eKey))
            {
                // Everytime dData will be filled with data from outside world
                OrderBook myOrder = new OrderBook();
                // Remove the key as the next object will be inserted somewhere else when new data arrives
                dData.TryGetValue(eKey, out myOrder);
                if (myOrder != null)
                {
                    foreach (var indiElement in TaskProcessor.lstInputsFromUser[eKey])
                    {
                        // If the data is already run for the expected number of cycles to total cyles, don't run again
                        if (indiElement.NoOfCycles != indiElement.TotalNoOfCycles)
                        {
                            var singleRetVal = new Task<ReturnStatus>( () => ProcessData(myOrder, indiElement));
                            singleRetVal.Start();
                            retValues.Add(singleRetVal);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Wait till all tasks are completed
                // Here also I am facing problem of how to wait on the 1-exchangekey and 5-tasks policy
                Task.WaitAll(retValues.ToArray());

                var results = retValues.Select(t => t.Result)
                     .ToList();

                if (results != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Shall print two times only");
                    foreach (var retResult in results)
                    {
                        if (TaskProcessor.ReturnStatusAfterCalc.Keys.Contains(retResult.ID))
                        {
                            TaskProcessor.ReturnStatusAfterCalc[retResult.ID] = retResult;
                            var myObj = TaskProcessor.lstInputsFromUser[eKey].FirstOrDefault(indi => indi.ID == retResult.ID);
                            if (myObj != null)
                            {
                                // Here I am unable to update my original object
                                myObj.NoOfCycles += retResult.CyclesCompleted;
                                /// arEvent.Set();
                                // Task.Run( () => Update database with myObj.NoOfCyles value for the listInputsFromUser[eKey]
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // TaskProcessor.ReturnStatusAfterCalc[retResult.ID] = new ReturnStatus();
                            TaskProcessor.ReturnStatusAfterCalc.TryAdd(retResult.ID, retResult);
                            var myObj = TaskProcessor.lstInputsFromUser[eKey].FirstOrDefault(indi => indi.ID == retResult.ID);
                            if (myObj != null)
                            {
                                // Here I am unable to update my original object
                                myObj.NoOfCycles += retResult.CyclesCompleted;
                                // Task.Run( () => Update database with myObj.NoOfCyles value for the listInputsFromUser[eKey]
                                // arEvent.Set();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The main problem is, the code runs multiple times the inner set of tasks than the required ones. Also I am facing problem in updating the actual object with return values as it is executing the inner tasks more than once.

Request anyone to help me on this. While(true) is bad but I will replace this with a set event included with Timer.

After couple of comments, I feel my example and explanation does not actually give problem description. Sorry for the trouble guys.

Problem Description:
say I am having 10 symbols from an exchange. User 1 is subscribed to 3 symbols and User 2 subscribed to 7 symbols. Now exchange will keep on sending data for these 10 symbols, User 1 and User 2 will give me certain price to place orders on these 10-symbols. I will be running 10 tasks to check the price for the incoming 10-symbols. Later User 1 also adds remaining 7 symbol price input. So I have to run 13 different tasks which takes 13 User Objects and 10-symbol data as each user object might contain different price and conditions

EDIT:

With the help from Panagiotis Kanavos, I realised Parallel.ForEach can be used to store the return results and Tasks are not required. The main logic presented here and rest of the unnecessary code is removed as per the comments.

Comment: Tried to add spaces for namespace but it is not showing as code fragment. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the edit guys, now it looks more readable.

Comment: There is a lot of code there to wade through, can you create a smaller example that duplicates your problem?

Comment: too much code!!... try with Task.WhenAll() to wait for your task

Comment: I tried my best to put it in small, but I felt I can't explain properly without showing a full cycle. I will try again.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi, I kept WaitAll() in two places to wait for the inner and outer tasks.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi, I kept async and await also, but it is still calling multiple times without waiting for the first set to complete.

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly what your problem is, but there is a lot of potential for this code to be creating a whole lot of `Task` objects. I don't know how much external data you are pulling and how many additional tasks each of those tasks creates, but this code honestly is in need of severe redesign. That would probably help to solve the problem you are having. On average, how many keys are you processing and then how many user objects are on average associated with those keys? From your code comments you mention at least 15 tasks running simultaneously.

Comment: @pstrjds, there might be 200-300 keys are expected and each key intern has 400-500 objects. I am open to redesign, but this is actually based on the number of keys and objects created. I can expect around 10k objects created.

Comment: @SNR `async/await` aren't broken. Your code though does a lot of weird things. eg, using `Thread.Sleep(1)`, using both `Task.Run` *and* `TaskFactory.StartNew`, using a list of Tasks - why?  And then `ProcessKeys` uses cold tasks? Even though it's *already* running in its own task? What are you trying to do? Why don't you simply call `Parallel.ForEach(dbData....)`? Don't try to reinvent

Comment: @SNR What are you trying to do? What is the actual problem you want to solve? Your code is essentially trying to reinvent TPL and the TaskScheduler. That's almost 90% of your code, which makes it impossible to understand what the code actually does.

Comment: @SNR - I removed my answer as I cannot reproduce your problem when I replace the `TryGetValue` with `TryRemove`, but as I stated earlier, this code needs to be redesigned. You are not going to gain processing efficiency by launching 10,000+ `Task` objects. Look into `Parallel.ForEach` as has been suggested.

Comment: Or ActionBlock<T>, if there is a steady stream of incoming events. The default Degree of Parallelism is 1 but you can change it to whatever is suitable for the machine and your throttling requirements

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, this is for algorithmic trading. Based on each symbol, I want to run tasks which is subscribed for that symbol. As we never expect the number of objects created by multiple users, I expected it is 10k+. I can start my tasks based on the data receiving from the third party.  Ex: I have subscribed to three symbols. There are 5 objects created for each symbol. I am getting continuous data for the three symbols which means my 15-tasks need to run. I can use ActionBlock<T> for events, but at certain point I have to run all user objects. Please guide me if there is any other way.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I can use Parallel.ForEach, but I have to get return values of my each inner task.

Comment: @SNR You want to process symbols, not start tasks. That's data parallelism. Data parallelism is provided by `Parallel.For/ForEach` and PLINQ. Both *do* return data, and you don't care whether `Parallel` uses tasks internally. Trying to create your own Task inside the `Parallel` method will only cause blocking, because `Parallel` uses at least as many tasks as there are cores to process the data.

Comment: ActionBlock or the Dataflow library isn't about events only. Nothing prevents you from using the last block in a pipeline to insert the data to a cache. A FAR better option though is to perform partial calculations as the data comes in. You don't need all the data to calculate an average, you can update a sum and count for each message.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I want to work on the data that is correct. Whenever I receive data, I will create a key, data pair so that I can actually work on the data. There will be multiple user objects to work on the data. So every user gives his own quantity and some price to and we have to check the data for all the user objects matching with key. I am trying to redesign it in another way, but honestly I am not getting any thoughts.

Comment: Furthermore, `Parellel.For/ForEach` have overloads with initialization, finalization steps that can be used to collect the data from all steps. That's similar to MapReduce.

Comment: @SNR assume that I've worked on algorighmic trading, even that I had to fix someone's "fast" C++ code to run on all 32 cores, not just a single one. The quick&dirty trick was to use C++ agents (similar to ActionBlock<T>) to process each symbol's stored data separately. Unfortunately, the boss decided that 12x improvement was enough. Your description is a bit vague so I can only give hints

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I don't have enough reputation to move this discussion to chat. Is it possible for you to do that? Sorry. I understood that if I move my code to Parallel.ForEach, then I can actually distribute it on all the cores. I am going through Parallel.ForEach to see how I can update my original User Object with the Number Of Iterations it had. I can remove that Task in inner function. Also, please can you tell me if there is a better way to do this? I can follow strategy pattern, but I am unable to link my requirement to that pattern.

Comment: What does `user objects to work on the data` mean? Are they actual users or agents that can be implemented eg with a TransformBlock or ActionBlock? One approach is to create one agent per symbol and store them eg in an array whose index corresponds to the symbol. That agent can process individual messages, cache them and process them. Parallelism comes from using multiple agents. Those agents can be implemented with custom DataFlow classes using eg [DatafloBlock.Encapsulate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228606(v=vs.110).aspx). The obvious drawback is that some agents may sit idle

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, say I am having 10 symbols from an exchange. User 1 is subscribed to 3 symbols and User 2 subscribed to 7 symbols. Now exchange will keep on sending data for these 10 symbols, User 1 and User 2 will give me certain price to place orders on these 10-symbols. I will be running 10 tasks to check the price for the incoming 10-symbols. Later User 1 also adds remaining 7 symbol price input. So I have to run 13 different tasks which takes 13 User Objects and 10-symbol data as each user object might contain different price and conditions.

Comment: @SNR this is data processing. These design patterns do not apply. You need to think about your algorithms first. How can you partition your input? By symbol is an obvious choice. What kinds of processing do you want to perform on them? Calculating averages is one thing. Triggering some action when a threshold is reached is another. Having an agent per symbol simplifies both - you can update partial sums, counts etc that are used to calculate statistics for each agent. You can also check the threshold (price?) for each incoming message and post a notification to *another* agent when required

Comment: @SNR put that last comment in the question itself, because that's the actual problem description.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131897/discussion-on-question-by-snr-process-multiple-tasks-return-values-in-task-paral).